# EJS - pass variable when include

Tags: ejs

I'm using ejs in backend with nodejs.
I'd like to pass variable when include. When include the header, pass the page title.

index.ejs:

```
<% include header %>
<body> . . . </body>
<% include footer%>
```

header.ejs:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title><%- my_tytle %></title>
</head>
```

footer.ejs:

```
</html>
```

How to pass `my_title` in the include command?

Comment: I think when `my_title` is defined inside index.ejs, it is also known inside the header-partial ...

Comment: can you elaborate with an example?

Answer (score 14):

You can pass the object inside the include statement

`<%- include("header",{title:"your_title"}) %>`

Comment: This is just including a "variable" that is hardcoded into your ejs, isn't it? How would you include a title from the server? <%- include("header",{title:<variableName>}) %> doesn't work.

Comment: This answer is acceptable because it's passing a variable, however, is a hard-coded value. So it's not the answer at all.

Answer (score 9):

you can pass `my_tytle` directly to the index.ejs and if there is a partial view for header,  `my_tytle` should be accessible to the header.

for example:
index.ejs:

```
<% include header %>
<body> . . . </body>
<% include footer%>
```

header.ejs:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title><%- my_tytle %></title>
</head>
```

now from node server if you pass the value for `my_tytle` to index.ejs, like this:

```
res.render('template_file.js', {
        my_tytle : "Value for your title"
    });
```

then your partial view (i.e header in your case) would be also able to access that variable.

Answer (score 1):

As asked somewhere in the comments, we can also use a variable to be controled by a server, and here is how:
`` <%- include("header",{my_tytle :`${myVar}`}) %> ``

Answer (score 1):

```
<%- include("header", locals) %>
```

All variables that are accessible in `index` will also be available in `header`.