# Node.js: EJS 2-level include with parameter

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs

Using a MEAN environment with EJS on the server side, I define many partials/templates, one of which is my header section.

```
//First include level (L1)    
<% include ../partials/header %>
```

Inside this header partial I also want to include several areas, e. g. a login or user-specific menu, depending on whether user is logged in or not.

```
//Second include level (L2)
//Inside header.ejs
<% if (req.user) { %> //---> req.user undefined
   <% include ../partials/login %>
<% } else { %>
   <% include ../partials/usermenu %>
<% } %>
```

As a matter of fact, I can't read any variables on this level. Neither req.user nor anything similar can be accessed. Any alternatives to get that info or maybe pass a parameter into header.ejs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found another way to do it (also the solution for: [EJS - pass variable when include](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23788810/ejs-pass-variable-when-include)). May come in handy for someone else. It's not my favourite solution as I had hoped to find a native way of accessing variables from inside includes without having to pass them in first so I consider this a workaround but in the end it works just fine.

When rendering the page where the first include (L1) was inserted, just make sure to pass in your data, that you want to handle on the lower levels like this...

```
app.route('/*')
.get(function(req, res) {
   res.render('pages/foo', { 
      login: req.user
   });
});
```

... and it will be accessible, no matter how many layers of inclusion you may introduce.